# This program about sorting values based on last digit of the value,but what if(i%10>j%10) return 1; else return-1; logic means?

Tags: java, collections

I'm learning basic java and I just reached on collection interface and now learning about sort method, so I know in this program the sort logic is based on the last digit of the values object and arrange values in ascending order bassing the last value but I did not get that how this method compare logic is doing it?

```
import java.util.*; 
    public class CollectionDemo{ 
       public static void main(String args[]){ 
       List values = new Arraylist<>(); 
       values.add(404); 
       values.add(908); 
       values.add(639); 
       values.add(265);

Comparator c =new Comparator(){ 
   public int compare(Integer i , Integer j) { 
      if(i%10>j%10) 
          return 1;
      else 
          return -1;
      }

};
 Collection.sort(values,c); 
    for(Integer o ; values) { 
      System.out.println(o); 
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Any compare method that has `return 1; else return -1` is **flawed** and **violates the contract** of the `Comparator` interface. If someone gave you code doing that, claiming that's how it's done, *stop listening to them*, because they obviously don't know what they are talking about!!!

Comment: Clearly that code didn't compile.  For one `Arraylist` should be `ArrayList`.  And you should be using `generics` in your `collections` and `Comparator`.

Comment: Just curious.  Considering that even with a properly implemented `Comparator` your results for the same list would not be consistent for the same data set.  In fact,  if all the values ended in the same digit, any shuffled set would retain its shuffled order after "sorting."  So what is the point of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Collections.sort()` method, you are passing 2 parameters. While passing "c", the logic that you implemented here -

```
Comparator<Integer> c =new Comparator<Integer>(){ 
   public int compare(Integer i , Integer j) { 
       int q=i%10;  //use local variables q and w
       int w=j%10;
      if(q>w) 
          return 1;
      else if(q==w) //add this to your code
          return 0;
      else 
          return -1;
      }

};
```

comes into action and thus the logic is implemented.Comparator interface is used to sort according to user defined criteria.
Now, in the logic, two integers are passed that are i and j. Modulus operator is returning the remainder on dividing by 10 , which returns the last digit of the number and that remainder is being compared here. If remainder of first integer being passed is greater, 1 is returned else -1 is returned.
Assume 123 and 345 are the numbers. 
Now, `123%10` returns 3 (remainder and also the last digit of number) and `345%10` returns 5.Then 3 and 5 are compared and -1 is returned.
The compare() method of Integer class of java.lang package compares two integer values (x, y) given
as a parameter and returns the value zero if (x==y), if (x < y) then it returns a value less than zero and
if (x > y) then it returns a value greater than zero. 

 So here it returns -1 indicating that second number is greater.

Comment: Just for the record: nonetheless that compare method is wrong, as it doesn't return 0 at all.

Comment: I recommend using two `local` variables to assign the mods to.  No reason to keep on computing that value.

Comment: @WJG Yes absolutely.

Comment: or just use `Integer.compare(int, int)` instead of all the `if`/`else` construct (or local variables)

Answer (score 1):

In the future please be sure to format your code so that it is easy to read. Also your question isn't very specific to which part of the logic you are unsure about.

Look into the [modulus operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) if you are not familiar with how that works, it gives you the remainder after division (e.g. 10 % 3 = 1). So when we compare 404 to 908 we check whether 404 % 10 > 908 % 10 or 4 > 8. 4 is not greater than 8 so we return -1. You should also check out the documentation for [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

We return -1 to indicate the second value is greater than the first, 0 to indicate they are equal, or 1 to indicate the first value is greater than the second.

Comment: Thank You All, Your Answers really helped me to understand this program, So nice of you all stay kind Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First things first according to the comment already fix the format of your code.
Second make sure your code compiles and you understand what you are doing atleast dont just dump some code from somewhere. You code dosen't even compile.
Third dont import the whole packages like this. Import only what is required.

Now talking about the code, hope you intend only to sort according to the last digit of the numbers. (not really "sort"). Here is an example which atleast compiles. (Sorry I didnot pay attention to much standards just a compiled version of the above)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(404);
        values.add(908);
        values.add(639);
        values.add(265);
        Comparator<Integer> c = new Comparator<Integer>() {
            public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
                if (i % 10 > j % 10)
                    return 1;
                else if (i % 10 < j % 10)
                    return -1;
                else return 0;
            }
        };
        values.sort(c);
        for (Integer o : values) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}
```

So here as you see we define the compare method within the comparator which compares the last digit of the numbers.(Incase you are not aware % 10 gives the last digit) This line then sorts the collection or the list implicitly by applying that comparator implementation.

This will be the result:

```
404
265
908
639
```

Hope that makes clear.

Comment: Just for the record: nonetheless that compare method is wrong, as it doesn't return 0 at all. That part missing from your answer leaves a huge problem around ...

Comment: and, since Java 1.7, with have `Integer.compare(int, int)` eliminating the need for `if`-`else`...or even `Integer.compareUnsigned(int, int)` (despite negative  numbers not being considered (apparently) on question)